# I can't show movies on my NEC projector

Tags: multimedia

I recently installed Ubuntu on my Sony VAIO. Since then, I can't show movies on my NEC projector. Although it displays the default picture of the lap top screen through the projector, it does not show anything else - neither text presentation, nor video or audio content. What can I do? please help.

Comment: A projector is the same as having a second monitor or TV. Same rules apply re: supported resolutions and extended, mirrored or single display. *"It displays the default picture of the laptop screen"* suggests extended desktop.

Answer (score 0):

As ChanganAuto suggests, this is likely because the projector is set as a "second display", which extends your desktop. You can control this in your display settings.

Here's how:

Right-click on your desktop and select "Display Settings". You will see a window that looks like this:

[image: Display Settings - Join Displays]

You now have three options:

| **Mode** | **Description** |
| --- | --- |
| Join Displays | Use all connected displays as one bigger screen ⇢ *Use this if you want to see different applications on different screens. You can drag the video player from the main screen (1) to the NEC projector (2).* |
| Mirror | Show the same image on every display ⇢ *Use this if you want the video to play on both the Sony display and the NEC projector at the same time. This may be distracting if you're going to watch movies in a darkened room, though.* |
| Single Display | Use *just* the display selected ⇢ *Use this and select "NEC projector" if you want *just* the projector to be used. Your Vaio's screen will turn off, and everything will run through the projector (until you disconnect the projector, then the notebook's display will come back on).* |

Choose the one that works best for you and enjoy your movies